# ComboBox.Value error - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Combobox in my Spreadsheet. I am trying to get the selected value from it. But not been able to do so.

These are the Codes that I tried:

```
Range("A1")=ComboBox1.SelectedItem
```

And

```
Range("A1")=ComboBox1.Value
```

Kindly help me with this. They both are not working.

This is how I added the Items to the Combobox:

```
For i = 2 To lastnum        
    disName= ThisWorkbook.Sheets(final).Range(Col& i).Value        
    With wb21Tool.Sheets("Main").ComboBox1        
        .AddItem disName        
    End With        
Next
```

Comment: What error do you get?  `Range("A1")=ComboBox1.Value` should work!

Comment: @MiguelH Object required - error

Comment: Try fully qualify your objects, try `wb21Tool.Sheets("Main").Range("A1").Value = wb21Tool.Sheets("Main").ComboBox1.Value` , it worked for me

Comment: @ShaiRado Worked. Can you add it as an answer. I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you add items to the combobox in the 'ThisWorkbook' 'Workbook_open()' object?

Comment: @MiguelH I didn't get your question. Sorry. I just did the basic way of selected the workbook and selected the sheet then the Combobox to add items. Kindly see the code that I have, it might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fully qualify your objects, try:

```
wb21Tool.Sheets("Main").Range("A1").Value = wb21Tool.Sheets("Main").ComboBox1.Value
```

Or,

```
With wb21Tool.Sheets("Main")
    .Range("A1").Value = .ComboBox1.Value 
End With
```